# How to generate custom keys from multiple arguments for caching abstraction in Spring 3.1?

Tags: java, spring, caching, key

[Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) gives an example how to compute a custom key from one of the arguments:

```
@Cacheable(value="book", key="isbn")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

However, what if I need to compute the key from several arguments? For example in

```
@Cacheable(value="book", key="???")
public Book findBook(String author, String title,
                     boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

**how would I compute the key from `author` and `title`?** So far I came up with ugly solutions like

```
author.hashCode() + 31 * title.hashCode()
```

Or I could create an external helper function like

```
public static int hashes(Object... args) {
    return java.util.Arrays(args).asList().hashCode();
}
```

and call it like `key="T(mypackage.MyHelperClass).hashes(author, title)"`. Still it's far from elegant.

(It seems to me that it'd be just easier if `@Cacheable` had `String[] key` instead of `String key`. For default keys, Spring has to combine multiple hashes into one anyway.)

Comment: you can use all SpEL features in key, like "#author + ' - ' + #title", which I suppose would be unique enough

Comment: @hoaz Good idea. In this example it seems quite reasonable as its unlikely that authors and titles would overlap. But if the objects have no meaningful and unique string representations it will not work.

Comment: as I have said SpEL is rich enough to do whatever you need to provide uniqueness, for your current question this simple key will work

Answer (score 1):

If you are on JDK 1.7, you can probably do something like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="book", key="T(java.util.Objects).hash(#p0,#p1)")
public Book findBook(String author, String title,
                     boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is not a hash! Don't create key with Objects.hash or similar.
Look in javadoc.

For your case create class ComplexKey with your fields, multi params constructor and generate hashCode and equals for this fields.